# weird CSS behaviour

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser, blogger

I installed a template on blogger, but it's not showing the background image.

in the [main blog here](http://www.martani.net/) you can see that there is no background image (the orange one)

now visiting [this one which is the blog I do test the template on](http://developper-talk.blogspot.com/) first, shows normally the background.

the weird result is that if you go back to [the first website](http://www.martani.net/) now and refresh it, the background will be shown??

how can that happen between 2 different domains? they both reference the same image but why it loads on [website1](http://www.martani.net/) only after loading [website2](http://developper-talk.blogspot.com/)?

this is the CSS associated

```
#body_top {
background:transparent url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_66wIGDjagHk/Sh1HpWevpII/AAAAAAAAAeo/L2BR0NJ6kB4/s1600/bgr_body_top.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some resource takes extremely long to load? Then visiting the second site causes it to be loaded to a cache - which acts as a reordering.

I'd suggest inspecting this behaviour with firebug - Network tab.

EDIT: weird, the firebug shows that server responds with 404

Appears like HTTP and not CSS bug. The server responds with 404 when connection is already open (keep-alive issue?) and returns the image otherwise.

OK, it's the **referer**. It should be blogspot.com subdomain.

Maybe blogspot has some sort of file size limit which disallows hot-linking of large files from other sites. The background_top seems somewhat larger than other files.

Here, look at blogspot.com referrer restrictions: http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=57527

Comment: Because the request is with different referers.

Comment: so blogspot is rejecting martani.net? why the other images load normally?

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. But if you send the request with blogspot referer it succeeds.

Comment: In short it looks like blogspot anti-hotlinking rules kick in.

Comment: thank you so much, I hosted it on another server and it's working, actually blogspot block any image more than 400px when you change to your custom domainame!